# Why no outputs?? I added a 'print' sentence at the last but it just does not get a output with no error

Tags: python, tensorflow

I added a 'print' sentence at the last but it just does not get a output with no error.

```
import xlrd
                 import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

data = xlrd.open_workbook('ML_data1.xlsx') #读excel文档

table = data.sheet_by_name('Sheet2') #读文档里的一个表格数据
table1 = data.sheet_by_name('Sheet3')


train_data = np.zeros((452, 279), dtype=float) #建立一个元素全为0的数组
train_data = np.float32(train_data)
train_label = np.zeros((452, 16), dtype=float)
train_label = np.float32(train_label)

for i in range(452):
    for j in range(279):
        train_data[i, j] = table.cell(i, j).value #将表格数据存入数组

for a in range(452):
    for b in range(1, 17):
        if(table1.cell(a+1, 0).value == b):
            train_label[a, b-1] = 1

x = tf.placeholder("float", [None, 279])
y = tf.placeholder("float", [None, 16])
def add_layer(inputs, input_node, output_node, active_function=None):
    w1 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([input_node, output_node]))
    b1 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1.0, output_node])+0.1)
    y1 = tf.matmul(inputs, w1) + b1

    if(active_function==None):
        outputs = y1
    else:
        outputs = active_function(y1)
    return outputs

y2 = add_layer(x, 279, 200, active_function=tf.nn.relu)
y3 = add_layer(y2, 200, 100, active_function=tf.nn.relu)
y4 = add_layer(y3, 100, 16, active_function=tf.nn.relu)

loss = tf.reduce_sum(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=y4,labels=y))
train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.01).minimize(loss)
corr = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y4, 1), tf.argmax(y, 1))
accr = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(corr, "float"))

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

sess= tf.Session()
sess.run(init)
for i in range(1000):
    sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={x: train_data, y: train_label})
if(i % 50 == 0):
    a = sess.run(loss, feed_dict={x: train_data, y: train_label})
    print("loss: %.3f" % a)
```

This is a simple BP network used to classify 16 classes. Dataset is a 542x279 matrix,which means there are 542 samples and per sample have 279 properties. The label is a 542x16 matrix.there is just one '1' and the other are '0' in every row,which means the accurate classification.

[image]

Comment: If you are getting an error, please post the complete Traceback and format it as code.

Comment: Any chance you can reduce that to an [mcve]?

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page.

Comment: Why was this downvoted ? Curious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will never print.  See my added comments.

```
for i in range(1000):
    sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={x: train_data, y: train_label})
# here, i = 999 : range(1000) goes from 0 to 999
if(i % 50 == 0):
    # 999 % 50 != 0, so no print!
    a = sess.run(loss, feed_dict={x: train_data, y: train_label})
    print("loss: %.3f" % a)
```

I think you intended for that last block to be indented (part of the for loop).  As written, it will never execute.